# How to compare two row and skip those two row in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql like below

| id | movement_qty | attribute_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 525 | 1000 |
| 2 | 630 | 1001 |
| 3 | -630 | 1001 |
| 4 | 700 | 1002 |
| 5 | -230 | 1003 |
| 6 | 900 | 1004 |
| 7 | -900 | 1004 |

I want the result like below

| id | movement_qty | attribute_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 525 | 1000 |
| 4 | 700 | 1002 |
| 5 | -230 | 1003 |

Here i want to skip those both of rows which attribute_id is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the window variant of `count`, and filter according to it:

```
SELECT id, movement_qty, attribute_id
FROM   (SELECT id, movement_qty, attribute_id,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY attribute_id) AS cnt
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  cnt = 1
```

Comment: #Mureinik, Thank you, i want to skip HAVING, finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be pretty simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY attribute_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```